# MVVM structure. Model classes

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Is it common to store "non-model" classes (maybe helper classes) that I don't wanna use in a ViewModel inside Model directory in MVVM project?

For example:

```
Models\SongModel
Models\ID3TagReader

ViewModels\SongViewModel
```

If no, how should I encapsulate these classes?

Comment: Maybe create a helper directory?

Comment: Depends if they relate to the `Models` directly. If they are only at `Model` scope they should be in the same namespace - if they can be used elsewhere, put them in the appropriate namespace/folder

Comment: There is no `MVVM` project, you are creating `wpf` project. And there are no rules of how to organize structure of that, but there are convenient ways of organizing things in wpf (to example, resource dictionaries). Regarding your question, don't put it inside `ViewModel`, make folder `Helper` or keep it unsorted - up to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this design, the views know of the ViewModel and bind to its data, to be able to reflect any changes in it. The ViewModel has no reference to the views—it holds only a reference to the model.

For the views, the ViewModel acts both as a façade to the model, but also as a way to share state between views (selectedContacts in the example). In addition, the ViewModel often exposes commands that the views can bind to and trigger.

refer to the link..

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2012/03/17/10284665.aspx